# Java Puro e Aplicativo para Android

Tags: java, android

Sou iniciante em Java. Preferi começar estudando Java puro, ou seja, descartei estudar através de arrastar componentes. Conheci o JavaFX; preferi estudar a construção desses componentes na mão também. Aprendi muitas coisas, muitas mesmo. Fiz algumas aplicações para *desktop*, mas não gostei da dificuldade em segurança e venda dessas aplicações; então, decidir começar a fazer aplicativos para Android.

Minhas perguntas são:

Como usar meus conhecimentos de Java e JavaFX no Android?

Por exemplo, aprendi a navegar entres telas de maneiras bem interessante, mas no Android, isso vai importar?

Em outras palavras, tem como programar em Android de uma maneira pura, sem ter que arrastar componentes toda hora?

Comment: Não confunda Android com Android Studio (IDE).

Answer (score 6):

Se você já sabe/tem conhecimento em Java, vai ter mais facilidade com o Android, uma vez que no Android Studio você irá trabalhar com java.. (Pode-se também desenvolver usando C# e JavaScript).

Em relação as interfaces, no Android, elas são arquivos XML. Então, você pode ou arrastar os componentes e posiciona-los onde for necessário ou cria-los usando apenas os códigos.

Por exemplo:
Você pode arrastar os componentes para criar a tela
[image: Tela arrastando os componentes]

Ou então, você pode escrever todo o xml. Para o exemplo acima, ficaria assim:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/configuracoes" />

</LinearLayout>
```

---

Vou deixar aqui, algumas referências para estudo:

[Developer Android](https://developer.android.com/)

Livro: [Google Android - 4ª Edição](http://www.novatec.com.br/livros/googleandroid4ed/)

Livro: [Google Android: crie aplicações para celulares e tablets](http://www.casadocodigo.com.br/products/livro-android)

Comment: Mas costumo criar botões, label etc... em java puro, não em xml; seria desnecessário fazer esses componentes dessa forma, já que se pode apenas arrastar.

Comment: @CarlosXimendes, existe a possibilidade de arrastar, acredito que seja uma questão de gosto fazer na mão ou arrastar

Answer (score 6):

O desenvolvimento Android, permite que você "arraste" os componentes para a tela, eu particularmente não gosto de fazer isso,mas o desenvolvimento de telas no android é bem intuitivo.

**Como usar meus conhecimentos de Java e JavaFX no Android?**

O desenvolvimento android nativo é feito por meio da linguagem Java então o que você aprendeu você poderá aplicar facilmente, no JavaFx colocamos ações para os botões:

```
myNode.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>()
```

No android existe uma forma quase identica onde podemos adicionar um método em nossos botões da mesma maneira

```
btEntrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
```

**Por exemplo, aprendi a navegar entres telas de maneiras bem interessante, mas no Android, isso vai importar?**

Novamente o Android studio é apenas uma IDE, no android a navegação entre as telas são feitas através de [INTENTS](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/reference/android/content/Intent.html), onde você cria uma intenção para startar a nova tela através de algum evento ou sucesso na validação de dados.

**Em outras palavras, tem como programar em Android de uma maneira pura, sem ter que arrastar componentes toda hora?**

Como citei na primeira pergunta é possível sim você cria seus layouts e dentro deles você pode colocar na mão cada componente que desejar ou fazer isso programando direto no Java.

Exemplo de algums componentes mais conhecidos:

**EditText** : exibe um campo para o usuário entrar com valores é possivel definir atributos para o mesmo, como permitir somente números ou text, tamanho, cores entre outros.

**Button**: Exibe um botão para o usuário, o mesmo tem diversas propriedades que  podem ser trabalhadas facilmente.

**TextView**: Funciona como uma label

Os livros que o emanuelsn citou são muito didáticos e podem te ajudar nessa etapa de adaptação, aqui no SOpt também temos diversas perguntas já respondidas relacionadas a tag `Android`.

**Paleta de componentes no Android Studio**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para utilizar é só expandir e arrastar o componente desejado.

[Documentação](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/reference/android/package-summary.html)

Comment: Eu gosto de arrastar os componentes e depois vou e edito como eu quero. ;)

Comment: haha, eu já não gosto fica tudo jogado na tela, hahaha

Answer (score 0):

Olha, na verdade o teu conhecimento em java vai contar bastante, tens de ter algum conhecimento de conceitos como orientação a objectos. Aconselho primeiro a ler sobre ciclo de vida e *threads* para Android.